# How to get rid of null values in my GridDB database?

Tags: python, mysql, desktop-application, griddb

I have a **GridDB** container for the **sqllite** database I am implementing into my **Student Management app**, but I need to GET RID of the NULL values on the database. How can I delete the rows and not make them appear on the app?
I have tried to
Here is an image of a sample of how the app looks like.[Five rows showing two NULL values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6pEL.png)

```
import pandas as pd
import griddb_python as griddb
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
import sqllite3

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()

try:
    gridstore = factory.get_store(host="127.0.0.1", port="8080", 
            cluster_name="Cluster12", username="root", 
            password="")
    conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo("Students_DB",
                    [              
                     ["Student ID", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                     ["First Name", griddb.Type.STRING],
                     ["Last Name", griddb.Type.STRING],
                     ["Gender", griddb.Type.STRING,
                     ["DOB", griddb.Type.STRING],
                     ["Current Year", griddb.Type.INTEGER],
                     ["CGPA", griddb.Type.FLOAT],
                    ],
                    griddb.ContainerType.COLLECTION, True)
    con = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)   
    # Reading Database into a Pandas DataFrame
    container = sqlite3.connect("StudentsDB.db")
    df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from best_students", container)


    # Adding the database
    for i in range(len(df)):
        ret = con.put(df.iloc[i, :])

except Exception as e:
    print(e)

sql_statement = ('SELECT * FROM Students_DB')
sql_query = pd.read_sql_query(sql_statement, con)

class Students(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        layout = AnchorLayout()
        title = MDLabel(
                            text = "Students Record Management(SRM)",
                            theme_text_color = "Custom",
                            text_color = (0, 0, 0, 1),
                            pos_hint = {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .8},
                            size_hint_x = 1,
                            halign = "center"
            )
#...
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure at what place you would like to remove the NULL values.
But griddb syntax accepts removing null using this syntax in the query:

`SELECT * from best_students where <columnName> IS NOT NULL`

Remember changing `columnName` to what ever column you prefer removing NULL from.

[EDIT] I saw you image later on.
If you like to remove NULL from Last Name you should write like this:

`SELECT * from best_students where 'Last Name' IS NOT NULL`